# Check circular reference within DataFrame (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a set of employee data where all employees report to a manager.
In the Data Frame, all employees are shown as an ID and each ID has a parent ID (the manager's ID).
Is there a way to check if any employee's reporting line direct back to themselves?

Example data frame:

```
pd.DataFrame({"id":[111,112,113],"parentid":[112,113,111]})
```

In this example employee 111 reports to 112, 112 reports to 113, 113 reports to 111. The line becomes a circular reference. Is there a way to check for this kind of circular reference?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for [`networkx`](https://networkx.org) to approach your data as a graph.

This is your graph:

[image: circular references pandas graph]

Create a directed graph and use [`simple_cycles`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.simple_cycles.html#networkx.algorithms.cycles.simple_cycles) to identify the circular references

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='parentid', target='id',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph)

list(nx.simple_cycles(G))
```

output: `[[112, 111, 113]]`

If you want to label the circular nodes, you can further use:

```
circular = {n for l in nx.simple_cycles(G) for n in l}

df['circular'] = df['id'].isin(circular)
```

output (on a more complex example):

```
    id  parentid  circular
0  111       112      True
1  112       113      True
2  113       111      True
3  210       211     False
4  211       212     False
```